# Why absolute path doesn't work for binary execution?

Tags: command-line, bash, docker

I am running Docker and I'm trying to use a binary which is located in a shared folder (I shared the folder via "-v host/folder/path:guest/folder/path"). The folder works fine, I am able to see the folder contents using ls and everything. However when I need to run my program like this:
/guest/folder/path/mybinary
it won't work. It says "No such file or directory"
However if I navigate to the folder and just use "mybinary", it works.

Any ideas of what could be the cause?
Thanks!

**Update**
I figured that running it without a specific path actually executes another version of it from the PATH. Which means that the path I'm trying to use never gets executed. Whether I use the absolute path or ./mybinary in the folder itself returns "No such file or directory"

Comment: Silly question but doesn't that binary have executable permissions set?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. After running file /path/to/mybinary I realized it was a 32bit binary so I had to install 32 libs. Then the problem went away!